# How to add a dynamic link {% url 'url_name' %} inside of a text field from Admin using Django-tinymce4-lite?

Tags: django, django-tinymce

SO tinymce4 lie allows me to enter a link but when I enter {% url 'somelink' %} it doesnt get rendered properly.

for example If my model is being render in the page of finance and I enter a link "2" the link would go to finance/2.

I want to be able to use the django {% url %} functionality inside of tinymce4-lie.

Any suggestion.

I have tried to insert a link but that was not rendered correctly

Answer (score 1):

This post, [render_as_template template tag](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1373/), might help you achieve that but please keep in mind that depending on what you do, this might cause a security issue, because what you actually want to do is injecting code inserted by a user (or admin in your case) into your website.

Therefore you will bypass any cross-site-scripting filters, etc., provided by Django.

If you just want to include a link, you have to at leas mark the variable as `safe` in your template. i.e. `{{ link_variable | safe }}`.

If you want a safer approach, you could just store the route_name and the id in two different db-values and render the link this `<a href="{% url route_name the_id_of_the_model %}">the link </a>` in your template.

And last but not least, you could write your own templatetag. Assuming you want to store something like "link_to model 4" and "link_to testpage". Then you can just pass the content to your own templatetag, where you split the string and calculate the url using the `reverse`, or `reverse_lazy` function of Django. Afterwards you can render it marked as safe again (here you need to call the `mark_safe` function - see [docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-template-tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-template-tags/) for more info).